# Vuex, firestore: Show the filtered result

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I want to add the filter function to my project.
Now I have a buttons component to trigger the filter search.

If I press the restaurant button, the result will be the shops that have a "Restaurant" value in the firestorm.

On the other hand, if I press the supermarket button, the result will be the shops that have "Supermarket" value in the firestore.

Now I am using vuex, and I am retrieving the data from "getMenuItems" using mapGetters in the Result.vue.

And the method I add in the Buttons.vue is, to trigger the mutation.
If I press the restaurant button, the restaurant data will be pushed into "restaurantItems" in menu.js.

What I want to achieve is that, if I press the restaurant button, the Result.vue will read "restaurantItems" instead of "getMenuItems".

I tried to use the if statement in computed property in Result.vue, but I could not find the solution.

If my approach is wrong, I am glad if you tell me the right way to make it.

**Buttons.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <section class="button-section">
            <div class="d-flex buttons">
                <b-button class="supermarket" @click.prevent="showSupermarket">Supermarket</b-button>
                <b-button class="restaurant" @click.prevent="showRestaurant">Restaurant</b-button>
        </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import fireApp from '@/plugins/firebase'
const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");
const db = firebase.firestore();
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import store from '../store'

    export default {
        name: 'Buttons',
        data() {
            return {
                supermarket: "",
                restaurant: ""
            }
        },
        methods: {
            showSupermarket() {
                const supermarketRef = db.collection('Product').where('type', '==', "Supermarket")
                supermarketRef.get()
                    .then(snapshot => {
                    if (snapshot.empty) {
                    console.log('No matching documents.');
                    return;
                    }
                    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        const supermarket = doc.data()
                        console.log(supermarket)
                        this.supermarket = supermarket
                        //triger mutation here.
                        this.$store.commit('showSupermarketResult', this.supermarket)
                        //console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                });
            },
            showRestaurant() {
                const restaurantRef = db.collection('Product').where('type', '==', "Restaurant")
                restaurantRef.get()
                    .then(snapshot => {
                    if (snapshot.empty) {
                    console.log('No matching documents.');
                    return;
                    }
                    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        const resutaurant = doc.data()
                        console.log(resutaurant)
                        this.resutaurant = resutaurant
                        this.$store.commit('showRestaurantResult', this.resutaurant)
                        //console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Result.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
    <Navbar />
    <Map />
    <Buttons />
    
    <div class="main">
        
        <section class="cards">
        <div class="card" v-for="(item, index) in getMenuItems" :key="index">
            <div class="card-icons" v-if="item.quantity > 0">
            <div class="card-icon">
            <div class="card__image-container" v-for="(sample, index) in item.sample" :key="index">
                <!-- <router-link to="/product"> -->
                <router-link :to="{name:'Product',params:{id:item.id}}">
                <img
                :src="sample"
                alt="Detailed image description would go here."
                />
                </router-link>
                <div class="card__content">
                    <div class="card__info">
                        <span class="text--medium">{{ item.business }}</span>
                        <span class="card__distance text--medium">{{ item.quantity }} left</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="icons">
            <div class="time">
                <span>until<br>{{ item.limitObject }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="fav">
                <span>Heart</span>
                </div>
                <div class="price">
                <span>{{ item.initial }}<br>{{ item.sale }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar.vue";
import Buttons from "@/components/Buttons.vue";
import Map from "@/components/Map.vue";
import fireApp from '@/plugins/firebase'
const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");
const db = firebase.firestore();
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'


    export default {
        name: "UserLocation",
        data() {
            return {
                address: "",
                error: "",
                spinner: false
            }
        },
        components: {
            Navbar,
            Map,
            Buttons
        },
        created() {
            //vuexfire
            const dbMenuRef = db.collection('Product')
            this.$store.dispatch('setMenuRef', dbMenuRef)
        },        
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters([
                'getMenuItems'
            ])
        },
        methods: {
            
        }
    }
</script>
```

**menu.js**

```
import { firestoreAction } from 'vuexfire'
import fireApp from '@/plugins/firebase'
const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");
const db = firebase.firestore();

const dbMenuRef = db.collection('Product')

const state = {
    menuItems:[],
    supermarketItems:[],
    restaurantItems: [],
    store:[]
}

const getters = {
    getMenuItems: state => state.menuItems,
    supermarketItems: state => state.supermarketItems,
    restaurantItems: state => state.restaurantItems
}

const mutations = {
    showSupermarketResult(state, supermarket) {
        state.menuItems.push(supermarket);
    },
    showRestaurantResult(state, restaurant) {
        state.restaurantItems.push(restaurant);
    },
}

const actions = {
    setMenuRef: firestoreAction(context => {
        return context.bindFirestoreRef('menuItems', dbMenuRef)
    }),
    
}

export default {
    state,
    mutations,
    getters,
    actions
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would refactor most parts of the codes in the question, since many of them are duplicates, such as:

**Buttons.vue**: Refactor button actions

```
<b-button class="supermarket" @click.prevent="showCollection('supermarket')">Supermarket</b-button>
<b-button class="restaurant" @click.prevent="showCollection('restaurant')">Restaurant</b-button>
```

**Buttons.vue**: Refactor methods

```
methods: {
    showCollection(type) {
        this.$store.dispatch('setCollectionType', type)
    }
}
```

**menu.js**: Move firestore logic into actions, with side effects

```
const state = {
    ...,
    currentType: 'menu'
}
const mutations = {
    ...,
    setCurrentType(state, type) {
        state.currentType = type
    }
}
const actions = {
    ...
    setCollectionType: ({ commit, state }, type) {
        commit('setCurrentType', type)
        const mutations = {
            supermarket: 'showSupermarketResult',
            restaurant: 'showRestaurantResult'
        }
        const states = {
            supermarket: 'supermarketItems',
            restaurant: 'restaurantItems'
        }
        if (state[states[type]].length) return
        const collectionRef = db.collection('Product').where('type', '==', type)
        collectionRef.get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                if (snapshot.empty) {
                    console.log('No matching documents.');
                    return;
                }
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data()
                    commit(mutations[type], data)
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('Error getting documents', err);
            });
        },
    }
}
```

**Result.vue**: and finally, refactor on how you would display the result

```
<div class="card" v-if="currentType === 'supermarket'" v-for="(item, index) in supermarketItems" :key="index">
    <!-- Iterate supermarket items-->
</div>
<div class="card" v-if="currentType === 'restaurant'" v-for="(item, index) in restaurantItems" :key="index">
    <!-- Iterate restaurant items-->
</div>
```

Comment: And every time I press the button, the items are added in the array. I think I need to fix this.

Comment: @YoheiUmezu You can always cancel unnecessary data update on `menu.js`, see my updated answer